# How to make my loop search for a blank space?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to do this exercise;

> Write a program that uses an array of char and a loop to read one word
>   at a time until the word done is entered. The program should then
>   report the number of words entered (not counting done). A sample run
>   could look like this:
>
> Enter words (to stop, type the word done): anteater birthday category
>   dumpster envy finagle geometry done for sure 
>   You entered a total of 7
>   words.
>
> You should include the cstring header file and use the strcmp()
>   function to make the comparison test.

Now, I searched for it on google and everyone just did it like; press enter after every word and when you finally enter after writing "done", the loop stops.

Now, I know how to do that.

What I want to do (and what I think the exercise actually wanted) is, for the user to enter a single string with multiple words, (for example: "pencil winter long sentence speak when old movies done now young not happen") and then the program should count every word before blank spaces (" " character) as a different word, find out where "done" is, and count every word before that.

Comment: `std::string::find` might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/
Will read a line until enter is pressed. You can divide parts of a string between the space character ' '(32 ascii). 
For counting words, this will work, where input is a string:

```
getline(std::cin, input);
int words = 0;
for (int c = 0; c < input.size(); c++) {
    while (input[c] != ' ' && c < input.size()) {
        c++;
    }
    words++;

}
```

Another way to do it is this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

```
while(strcmp(tmp.c_str(),"done") != 0){
      std::cin>> tmp;
      words++;
    }
```

cin naturally stops recording the string at every space